# Storing Times and Dates in a Database back end

Tags: sql, database, datetime

What are the pros and cons for storing a date in a SQL database as a Date datatype versus storing the year, month, day, etc in separate columns using an integer data type? I noticed that the database back end for an application where I work separates all dates into columns of integers for days, months, years. Why would the developers have used this schema?

Comment: If you do a lot of work based on just those fields (like "find all transactions in any April" or "update all rows where day of month = 1"), I suppose that indexing the separate values would have minor performance benefits.  But the additional cost in complexity in your application and presentation layers would far outweight any minor benefits, imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea of using Date data type is that you can comfortably use DB commands like that: GIVE ME records WHERE date from 01-10-2014 08:30 UTC to 04-10-2014 02:30 UTC. In DB system need to look and compare only one field before returning result otherwise system needs to check several columns before returning the result.

I would not recommend you to use few fields for displaying dates. Use classic. :) 
Such realisation like in your description can be explained only that app doing some special operations with dates.

Answer (score 1):

Some cons . . .

- It's a *lot* more complicated to keep bad dates out of the database. Feb 29, 2014 is not a valid date, but Feb 29, 2016, is.
- Date arithmetic is more complicated.
- It's not unusual for a date or a timestamp to be part of a compound key. Splitting up a date value into multiple columns makes foreign key references much more work.